# This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle

[This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XT8i.png)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'H:\Flutter_Projects\xylophone_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

As a requirement in uploading debug symbol files, version of the Android Gradle plugin is 4.1 or higher as mentioned in this SO post:

> Before you can upload debug symbols files, you must be using Android
> Gradle plugin version 4.1 or higher.
>
> Looks like it will come only with Android Studio 4.1, because I can
> only get Gradle 4.0.0 automatically now.
>
> So I suggest you to return classic Play console and it will let you
> through :)

And for the Flutter side, there is actually an [open GitHub ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60240) that's being monitored by the Flutter team.